# Python PIL get pixel color for Steam games

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Right now I'm using `PIL.ImageGrab.grab()` to capture the screen. At this point I can use `getPixel()` to return an rgb value to work with. This works wonderfully if I'm capturing a browser or whatnot, but if I try to run Fallout 4 I notice the function is returning all black pixels. Is there anyway to capture its pixels properly?

The alternative I can think of is to capture from a webcam, but I would expect a bigger performance hit. The whole purpose of this is to get the average rgb from the screen and transmit it to a Philips hue light. This would be awesome to have working with a game!!

Comment: this has to do obviously with trying to grab framebuffers coming from opengl or dx. I'm not sure if PIL is able to do that. I know that the only efficient way to do that is using a proxy dll in order to inject some framebuffer dumping code. Other than that, webcam, sounds the less pain one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you think it would be very slow reading from the framebuffer? If so I might try the webcam route.

Comment: Capturing the framebuffer through some dx hook, should be very efficient, and very fast. PIL and obviously webcam routes are completely out of the rendering pipeline and therefore they should be really slow.